# Installing JDK on Amazon linux box gives error: open of <html> failed: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rpm, java

I just got a new amazon linux box and I'm trying to install jdk on it. These are the commands i followed but I am getting an error:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (amazon-62.1.11.11.90.55.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

$ wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm

$ ls
jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm

$ ls -al jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm 
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 5307 Mar 20  2012 jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm

$ sudo rpm -i jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm 
error: open of <html> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <head> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <title>Unauthorized failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Request</title> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <META failed: No such file or directory
error: open of NAME=ROBOTS failed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because attempting a wget is redirecting you to an HTML page, presumably demanding you accept their terms and conditions first. Running your wget command reveals this:

```
--2013-10-14 18:16:42--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm
Resolving download.oracle.com... 23.62.239.25, 23.62.239.8
Connecting to download.oracle.com|23.62.239.25|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm [following]
--2013-10-14 18:16:43--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com... 23.65.6.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com|23.65.6.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2013-10-14 18:16:45--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com|23.62.239.25|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘jdk-7u1-linux-i586.rpm’
```

The important line is right here:

```
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
```

Looking at the [README.md](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/java/blob/master/README.md) in the OpsCode java cookbook reveals the following:

```
IMPORTANT NOTE

As of 26 March 2012 you can no longer directly download the JDK from Oracle's 
website without using a special cookie. This cookbook uses that cookie to 
download the oracle recipe on your behalf <snipped>
```

But then looking in the [oracle.rb recipe](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/java/blob/master/recipes/oracle.rb), you can see the following:

```
if tarball_url =~ /example.com/
  Chef::Application.fatal!("You must change the download link to your private repository. You can no longer download java directly from http://download.oracle.com without a web broswer")
end
```

This means that you need to install via apt/yum/whatever from a repository that has the latest JDK 7 package, or head over to the [OpenJDK project](http://openjdk.java.net/) and download from there.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to download the rpm with this command `wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=xxx;" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u25-b15/jdk-7u25-linux-x64.rpm`